# Phoenix function semantic action not compiling

Tags: c++, boost, lazy-evaluation, boost-spirit, boost-phoenix

I wish to parse a string and ensure that it is lower case.

It has to be done at this stage because spirit builds tree out of it all.

so I have this rule

```
struct to_lower_object
{
    typedef char result_type;

    char operator()(char a) const
    {   
        return std::tolower(a);    
    }   
};


int main()
{

boost::phoenix::function<to_lower_object> lazy_lower;

qi::rule<std::string::iterator, char() >
    lower_char=(qi::char_-":")
    [
         qi::_val=lazy_lower(qi::_1);
    ];

qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::string() >
    lower_string =
        +lower_char; 
:::
```

problem is that it doesn't compile, the error is massive also, to big to post.

Thanks

EDIT: I fixed the operator overload, that was my bad, but the problem persists. I beleive* it is to do with the placeholders

EDIT2: I have split the problem up to ensure that it is working on a char and not a series of them, but it still isn't working with the same reams of errors.

Comment: Are you using Phoenix v2 or v3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after much torment I finally got it working.

This:

```
struct to_lower_object
{
    typedef char result_type;

    char operator()(char a) const
    {   
        return std::tolower(a);    
    }   
};
```

Should have been:

```
struct to_lower_object
{
    template<typename Arg>
    struct result{
        typedef char type;
    };  

    template<typename Arg>
    char operator()(Arg arg1) const
    {   
        return std::tolower(a);    
    }   
};
```

Super. This apparently is because I was reading some old docs.

Comment: This change only makes sense if you're using Phoenix v2. I.e., if you're actually using Phoenix v3, your 'before' code is already ideal.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that the line `qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::string() >` will never compile. Did you mean `qi::rule<std::string::iterator, std::string >` ?

Comment: No that is just how spirit it implemented for some reason, with out the semantic action, it compiles and runs as expected with std::string(), and doesn't without. All there doc show them passing OutputType()